# Flash Builder: How to verify if the date has been selected in datechooser component?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I am trying to verify if the users select a date in my date chooser spark componet. I tried:

```
if(dateChooserBegin.selectedDate){
..........
}
```

I will get a run time null object error. I was wondering if anyone here know to do this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you traced through your code?  Which value is null?  ( dateChooserBegin or selectedDate? )  Based on your code, I would only expect a null error if dateChooserBegin was null.  Because you can't drill down into properties on null objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to extract the date from the `CalendarLayoutChangeEvent` event object that is raised on choosing a particular date. See the [example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d9b.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63b33-7fd3) on Flex livedocs (particularly the `useDate` event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Best way I can think of is adding on to what dirkgently said. Set on onChange event on the dateChooser to change a global boolean value to true. Then in your if() check if the boolean is true. Only other method I can think of to ensure that ANY date is set is to use a selectedDate on the dateChooser itself, forcing a default date in there.